# Dungeon Siege 3: Item Color

Tags: dungeon-siege-3

I've found various colored items in Dungeon Siege 3, I assume they denote some sort of rarity scale. Does anyone have a list of these various item types/ranks that can be found?

Comment: Gray -> Green -> Blue -> Orange; that's my experience from the demo, anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are three colors corresponding to randomly generated loot:

- White: common
- Green: uncommon
- Blue: rare

Generally, the rarer the item, the better attributes it has.

There's an additional color, orange/brown, which corresponds to artifacts. Artifacts are unique items that are not randomly generated: they always have the same statistics and are always located in the same place.